# What kind of bonds (σ or π) are formed by px, py and pz orbitals?

Tags: bond, orbitals

Our chemistry teacher said that two  $\mathrm{p}_z$ orbital only form sigma bond whereas  two $\mathrm{p}_x$ and two $\mathrm{p}_y$ orbitals form only pi bond.

He also stated that only $\mathrm{p}_z$ orbital forms a sigma bond with the $\mathrm{s}$  orbital.

But in our book it is written that $\mathrm{p}_x$, $\mathrm{p}_y$, and $\mathrm{p}_z$ orbitals can form both sigma and pi bonds.

Please give me the correct explanation.

Comment: See, the three p orbitals look exactly the same. How do you know which of them is px and which is pz?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Ok so does that mean that any p orbital can form a sigma or pi bond.

Comment: Yes and no. Some people (including you teacher) use a different convention.

Answer (score 4):

It's a question of

(1) labeling conventions (what you call x, y and z in the coordinate system defining the position of two bonded atoms)

and

(2) the orientation of the two overlapping orbitals from the bonding atoms

If an overlap maximum occurs on the internuclear axis between the atoms, you call the resulting bonding orbital a "sigma" orbital. If maximum overlap occurs on an axis parallel to the internuclear axis, you call this type of bonding "pi". Either s or p orbitals can form sigma bonding orbitals, but s orbitals generally form sigma orbitals, whereas of the 3 conventional p orbitals, only one has lobes oriented along the internuclear axis (this orbital is usually called $p_z$ because its principal symmetry axis coincides with the internuclear axis, which is also labeled the z axis) and forms sigma bonding orbitals. The remaining two (x and y) form pi orbitals. This is illustrated schematically in the following figure:

[image]

(note the AOs don't overlap significantly, focus is on showing their relative orientation and labels)

Comment: I appreciate to explain the following paragraph by using a picture "only one has lobes oriented along the internuclear axis (usually called $p_z$ because its principal symmetry axis coincides with the internuclear axis which is also labeled the z axis) and forms pi bonding orbitals. "

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh Thanks for bringing the garbled sentence to my attention. Also, I added a figure.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. I wanted to clarify a point. If we had taken the x axis(vertical direction ) as the internuclear axis then we would say that only the px orbital forms sigma bond and pz and py orbitals form pi bonds. It depends on which axis we want to place the nucleus of the atoms . Please correct me if I have misunderstood. Thank you

Comment: @AshokSharma Yes that is correct. But beware conventions, as I mention in my answer. If you have two atoms, some people (maybe your teacher) might always use the convention that the internuclear axis is the "z" axis and call the orbital on that axis pz.

Comment: Is it by convention that $p_z$ orbitals lies on the plane?

Comment: @Kaushik There is a lot of freedom in deciding what you call the "z" coordinate, but usually the convention is that x and y are related by a rotation symmetry whereas z is unique and not related to x or y by a rotation.

Comment: If $p_z$ is considered to be internuclear axis, then which orbital is filled first? Is it $p_x, \ p_y \ or \ p_z$? In this convention $p_z$ is forms sigma bond. Isn't? And if the order of filling $e^-$ is $p_x, \ p_y \ or \ p_z$ , how is $\sigma$ bond formed before $\pi$ bond (which is true) ? Because $p_x$ orbital is filled first which forms $\pi$ bond by the convention we chose? What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Sigma bonds usually form first (lower in energy), so in this case pz would be filled first. But I'd hate to generalize without knowing what particular problem you are referring to.

Comment: @BuckThorn please check the edited comment. please let me know if you don't understand my comment

Comment: @Kaushik The orientation of the orbitals between the atoms is more important then what you call them (x,y or z). If x lies in the internuclear axis, then px is involved in sigma bonds.

Comment: So orbital along internuclear axis is always filled first.

Comment: @Kaushik Please see my previous comments.